# Groovy YamlBuilder field case

Tags: groovy, yaml, yamlbuilder

I'm trying to generate a cloudformation template with groovy YamlBuilder, that's why case matters here. The issue is that by default YamlBuilder converts pascal-case fields to camel-case.

Please see the example (runnable via groovyConsole):

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder

class Person {
  String Name = 'Mickey Mouse'
}

YamlBuilder builder = new YamlBuilder()

builder {
  Node new Person()
}

builder.toString()
```

The code above returns "Name" field in lower case:

```
---
Node:
  name: "Mickey Mouse"
```

I need:

```
---
Node:
  Name: "Mickey Mouse"
```

I've tried plenty of options but haven't found how can I tell YamlBuilder to keep "Name" field case. Or maybe I can use some annotations over the field?